# Decomposition of a symmetric matrix into multiplication of two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What is the necessary condition for a real symmetric matrix $ A_{m\times m} $ to be written as $B*B^T$ where $B$ is an $(m\times 1)$ matrix ?

Comment: $B*B^T$ will have rank 1

Comment: then it is not possible unless $A$ has only one independent row/column. Thanks!

Comment: Consider answering your own question and accepting it.

Comment: Also relevant to see: The matrix will be semi-positive definite. Also, the numbers on the diagonal have to have squareroots.

Comment: How about the more general case $A=B*C$ where  $C$ is a $1\times m$ matrix and $A$ is a general matrix ?

Answer (score 2):

*I'll answer the question from OP's comment:*

> How about the more general case $A=B∗C$ where $C$ is a $1×m$ matrix and $A$ is a general matrix ?

Take $A={\vec B}^T\vec C+{\vec C}^T\vec B$. Then $A$ is symmetric, due to
$$
A^T=\left({\vec B}^T\vec C+{\vec C}^T\vec B\right)^T=\left({\vec B}^T\vec C\right)^T+\left({\vec C}^T\vec B\right)^T={\vec C}^T\vec B+{\vec B}^T\vec C=A
$$